# Как поставить checkbox вместо значение из бд

Tags: c#, sql-server, checkbox, datagridview

Суть вот в чем. В базе есть таблица "table1"[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Она отображается в datagridview на форме при помощи:

```
        SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection(connectionstr);
        conn1.Open();
        SqlCommand comm1 = conn1.CreateCommand();
        string command = @"SELECT [column1] as 'Отметить записи для отправки',[column2]  as 'Номер письма',[column3]  as 'дата письма',[id_table]  FROM [table1]";
        comm1.CommandText = command;
        SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter();
        da1.SelectCommand = comm1;
        DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
        da1.Fill(ds1, command);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds1.Tables[command];
        conn1.Close();
```

Как сделать вместо значений "null" в "Отметить записи для отправки" checkbox'ы?
А также при нажатии на эти checkbox'ы в базе менялось значение на true\false или 0\1?

Answer (score 1):

Если столбец будет иметь тип bool (bit) он будет автоматически представлен на DataGridView в виде столбца с CheckBox`ами, ну а изменение повесьте на событие Cellclick

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.